# Mining an image out of an acess database into a GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, ms-access, gridview

I'm building an ASP.Net web application that has an Microsoft Access database behind it. At the database, I have a table called `items`. one of it's columns is `image` - which is a visual representation of the item, which is a hyper link to an image on the database computer.

I have two questions:

First of all, is this a bad design? would you rather save the image itself on the database? If so, how would you do it?

The second one is, how can I represent an image saved this way in a gridView?

I've tried the following in C#;

Filling a dataset with an OleDbCommand:

`SELECT ItemName as Name,ItemPicture as Picture...`

And setting it as the source of the GridView, but sadly, it just wrote out the hyperlink in the grid:
`1.jpg#1.jpg#` instead of showing the image.

How would you do it?

Comment: You need to bind src to the img.

Comment: can you give an example of what is actually stored in the image field? Is it a path to the image?  A fully formed html hyperlink? Or is it a binary object?

Comment: @fnostro What's stored in the database is the path to an image. I want to have an actual picture (not a link to it ) in the grid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this a bad design

Generally speaking, no.

There are plenty of white papers on the subject of storing images as BLOB's inside a database versus using the OS File System.  You'll have to do the research to determine which is right for you.  But given that you're using Access I'd avoid storing the images in the database as Access has an upper limit of 2GB for the overall file size of the database. Images can fill that up pretty quickly.

Assuming the image field is a relative path to the associated file, all you should have to do is add an `ImageField` to the `Gridview` and bind the image URL field to the `DataImageURLField` property.

```
<asp:ImageField DataImageUrlField='<%# Bind("Picture") %>'></asp:ImageField>
```

This assumes your ItemPicture field contains a string similar to this: "/images/1.jpg". If the image field is literally a hyperlink (an html `<a>` tag) then you could instead add a `TemplateField` to the Gridview and in the ItemTemplate add an ` control and bind it similarly:

```
<asp:TemplateField>
  <EditItemTemplate>
  </EditItemTemplate>
  <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Literal ID="Literal1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Picture") %>'
  </ItemTemplate>
<asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: What do you mean by Bind("Picture")? Is the picture suppoused to represend a path in the database system?
Thank you very much in advance. (:

Comment: In addition, will it fit if I set it for a URL?

Comment: Your select statement: `SELECT ItemName as Name,ItemPicture as Picture...`, so Picture is the field name from your sql statement.  When you use a Gridview, at some point, either in the markup or programmatically, you attach it to a data source.  This is what is meant by _binding to a data source_

Comment: if you use a Gridview ImageField the default dimensions will be the height and width of the contained image.  But you can specifiy the `Height` and `Width` using the ImageField properties to limit the display size to whatever is acceptable for your situation.